# Как сделать условие из таблицы в БД по запросу

Tags: sql, delphi, sql-server

Пишу на Delphi.

Задача - Нужно сделать условие в таймере. Если статус равен 0 и получатель равен "бунт", то выдает сообщение: "Вам пришло новое сообщение".

На практике имеем запрос AdoQuery1.AdoQuery1->Property->SQL->редактор, в котором я написал куда ему обращаться

```
select * from [dbo].[ResultProbLab] where ( [Status]='0' and [Poluch]='БУНТ')
```

Но как теперь написать условие в таймере для вывода сообщения на экран?
Таймер сам работает каждые 30 секунд, он должен проверять это условия, как случилось, так выкидывает сообщение.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, я не понимаю, как это присвоить, чтоб он отрабатывал.

Comment: Пожалуйста добавьте ваш пример кода, чтобы было понятно, что вы пытались сделать и как.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался сам
Код из таймера

```
procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
var rez : TModalResult;
begin
try
adoconnection1.close;
adoconnection1.Open;
if (ADOConnection1.InTransaction)  then
ADOConnection1.RollbackTrans();
ADOConnection1.BeginTrans();
ADOQuery5.Active:=true;

//----------------Уведомление о новых сообщениях-----------------

ADOQuery1.Open;
Label2.caption:=ADOQuery1.Fields[0].asString;
ADOQuery1.Close;
if Label2.caption='False' then
begin
Timer1.Enabled := False;
rez:= MessageDlg('Вам пришло новое сообщение', mtConfirmation, [mbOK], 0);
Timer1.Enabled := True;
end;

//----------------Уведомление о новых сообщениях-----------------
 except
on e:Exception do
  begin
 ShowMessage('Нет связи c сервером.')
  end;
end;
end;
```